# Send and Receive from a single DatagramSocket in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets

Is it possible to use a single DatagramSocket to send and receive packets in a single Java application? I have been attempting to do this using threads but have had not luck. Every socket tutorial I find online uses separate client and server classes to send data. However, in my case, I want the client and server to reside in a single application. Below is my attempt:

```
public class Main implements Runnable {

// global variables
static DatagramSocket sock;
String globalAddress = "148.61.112.104";
int portNumber = 9876;

byte[] receiveData = new byte[1024];

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    sock = new DatagramSocket();

    (new Thread(new Main())).start();

    // send data
    while (true) {
        InetAddress IPAddress = InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1");
        int port = 9876;
        int length = 1024;


        byte [] sendData = new byte[1024];
        String message = "hello";

        sendData = message.getBytes();

        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData, sendData.length,
                IPAddress, port);

        sock.send(sendPacket);

    }
}

public void run() {
    //get incoming data
    while (true) {
        byte[] sendData = new byte[1024];

        DatagramPacket receivePacket = new DatagramPacket(receiveData,
                receiveData.length);

        receivePacket.setPort(portNumber);

        try {
            sock.receive(receivePacket);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        String sentence = new String(receivePacket.getData());
        System.out.println("RECEIVED: " + sentence);
    }
}
```

}

As you can see I am sending data in a loop on the main thread and receiving data on the loop in the runnable thread. The main thread should continuously send "hello" to the receiver and output the message. However, no output is given?

Am I on the right track here? Is using threads the best way to do this? Is this even possible? And if so is there a better solution?

Comment: There is no such things as client/server with UDP. UDP is connectionless.

Comment: I can't see any such thing. Where's the run() method? And what does 'not luck' mean?

Comment: If you scroll down in the code you will see the run method. I intended to say 'no luck'.